# Watchdog/recovery mechanism for realtime embedded system (using heartbeat, exceptions and Posix signals)?

Tags: error-handling, embedded-systems

We have a large(ish) real-time embedded system. It's VxWorks, if that makes any difference. It has some C code in DKMs, but is 95%+ in C++.

It has absolutely no exception handling, nor Posix signal handling. It is multi-threaded, so if one thread/process/subsystem dereferences a null pointer, or access a non-existent vector entry, etc, I guess that it just dies(?) and the rest of the system ... limps along without it?

We need a robust mechanism to handle such anomalies and keep the system running smoothly, unattenuated, without human intervention.

Here are my first, somewhat jumbled, thoughts, and I would appreciate any comments on whether this is too simple, too complex, missing something, etc. I am sure that this is industry standard and that there are accepted best engineering practises. What are they?

For the C code, I plan to add a signal handler to catch segmentation faults, etc.  It would be too much effort to add meaningful exception handling to the C++ code, so I had thought a single try/catch around the `main()` function. However, while those can log & swallow "a bad thing happened", I am not certain that they can identify the offending software and "make it better", and it seems a bit heavy-handed to restart everything, rather than just the offender.

Perhaps (the above combined with) a watchdog or heartbeat mechanism?

A watchdog in `main()` could know the process Id of each thread, since it started them, and periodically check their status, killing and restarting any which are hanging or have died.

Or a heartbeat mechanism, where the `main()` periodically sends a message to each thread and start a timer. If the timer expires before an ACK is received, kill & restart the thread (I use the term thread loosely; they might be processes).

The above sounds sort of vague, but is perhaps a reasonable start. What is a good design, preferably one used often in similar circumstances?

---

[Update] After investigation, I find that our C++ code builds on a framework, which we cannot alter, and which runs everything as threads, nor processes.

My latest proposal is that we:

- handle errors in the C code by signal handler (whether one or one per DKM, if these are processes)
- add a single try/catch around the `main` function

  - both of the above will log the problem to a disk file with as much diagnostic information as possible and "somehow" restart all of the software (as opposed to individual threads)
- when the system starts up, it will launch a watchdog process. This process will launch the application as a single process and monitor it at regular intervals. If it cannot be found, or is "stuck", then it will be (killed and) restarted.

I do not see much point in complicating the watchdog process, which **must** be robust and should never fail. To that end, I am not sure of the advisability of a heartbeat or handshake keep-alive mechanism. If we, then I would imagine a single interchange between the watchdog process and the application process, but that would only be meaningful if the the application process had a similar monitor/handshake mechanism with each of its threads.

I will put that to the powers that be and see just how much robustness they wants and how much effort they are willing to invest. If it helps anyone to comment, this is a [DAL D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178C#Software_level) project, so not overly critical.

Comment: I guess you do realize that a signal handler, to be safe, can do almost nothing? I.e. calling external code is dangerous.

Comment: If the goal is to have the app be restarted, and if there is a Watchdog process, what would you recommend? Could the app restart itself? Kill itself and let the watchdog spot that & restart it? Write to a disk file? We will settle for "if something goes wrong (terminate and ) restart the app". I hope that you can post a suggestion as an answer

Comment: Kill the process and let the watchdog restart the process. You can write to or simply touch a file to update a timestamp, to see if the process is alive. Make sure you don’t start a duplicate. You could also use a shared object in the OS to signal. The other responders all have excellent advice. Read up a bit on your OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VxWorks documentation uses the word "task" to refer to what
traditional systems call a "thread".
I will refer to the concept as "thread" here, given the audience.

## failure domains

You repeatedly confuse "thread" and "process" in your description.

A process has one or more threads of execution,
all sharing the same address space.
If any of its threads corrupts memory with Undefined Behavior
like a null dereference, then the whole process should exit.
And in your use case, it sounds like you want to immediately restart it.

You don't have a choice in this.
Once a thread within a process fails,
the entire process fails, including all of its threads.

So we have failure domains at the granularity of processes.
It makes sense to restart a failed process.

I'm willing to believe this bullet point from
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VxWorks#Features):

> - User-mode applications ("Real-Time Processes", or RTP) isolated from other user-mode applications as well as the kernel via memory protection mechanisms

So processes are protected from one another, similar to traditional systems.
When I say "traditional", think of Linux, FreeBSD, MacOS, Windows.
Non-RTOS systems with the usual notions of processes and threads.

VxWorks configures the
[MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)
so that a given process is simply **unable** to change
the memory of another process.
It cannot corrupt another process in that way.

The various threads of a process, OTOH,
share memory and can cause corruption visible to peer threads,
which is why we restart the whole process after an error.

I am ignoring the < 5% C code in DKMs that you mentioned,
since those loadable kernel modules have been given
high privilege and can do a great deal of harm if they're buggy.
Failure in a DKM should typically imply a reboot of the host.
Don't deploy buggy DKM code.

## nannies

It sounds like one or more of your apps exhibit occasional
buggy behavior which leads to the app crashing and exiting.
If you usually launch `app1`,
but want immediate restarts after such an exit,
just launch `app1_nanny.sh` instead:

```
#! bash

while true
do
    app1
    echo Restarting at $(date)
done
```

It's a very simple nanny script that keeps an eye
on that wayward app.

I will usually put a brief `sleep 1` before the `echo`,
to avoid burning CPU cycles needlessly if the app
manages to get into a mode where
it happens to fail immediately upon startup.

## watchdog timer

Some buggy apps will hang instead of exiting.
Asking the app to log a heartbeat message every K seconds is a good idea.

Have a very simple companion process read the log
or otherwise look for those heartbeats.
When 2 × K seconds have elapsed without a peep,
it should send a `kill` signal to the buggy app,
making it drop out.

The idea here is that the companion process is so simple
that it can't show buggy behavior, it is always available.
It's the same rationale for the nanny parent process
which spawns a buggy child application process.

## log analysis

It sounds like you have a complex system,
with multiple components,
which you do not yet understand.
You want to fix that.
You will need to identify the Root Cause of an observed failure
if you ever hope to bug report it and obtain a software fix.

Crank up the log level of components you suspect of being buggy.
Send logs to an analysis host, which can filter "routine, boring" messages.
Each time there's an observed failure,
assign a staff member to write a report of what was observed,
what the suspected Root Cause is,
and what bug report fixes you're awaiting.
You need a process to track the details,
so you can systematically eliminate one Root Cause after another.

## simplify

Your host is running too many things.

Buy another host. Run a subset of those things. Measure
[MTBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures)
and contrast the two systems.
Does the simpler setup fail less often?
*Which* app(s) seem to be the culprit?
Is system load relevant?
Is there some "kiss of death" network input
that always crashes an application?

You have lots of debugging work ahead of you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for some excellent feedback. I hope that I have clarified the process/thread thing in the updated question. Its a single process, with multiple threads. I think that I will add a second, "nanny", process as watchdog. We do, of course, have to cater for the DKMs, with one or ore signal handlers (tbd). Yes, we do log file analysis & bug fixing, but nothing is perfect, so we need a final "catcher in the rye" when deployed in the field (See what I did there? ;-) And, the more I look at it, the simpler it should be - any problems, log the problem, then (terminate and) restart the app.

Comment: You have a single app1 process that is flaky. It likely has more than a Single Responsibility. Find some responsibility that you can rip out and assign to a _new_ app2 process, so you have a pair of _simpler_ processes. Monitor MTBF. Rip out app3 functionality if you can. // The DKMs _must_ be rock solid. Evict flaky logic into an app process in order to simplify them. // A watchdog monitor process (which sends a `kill`) is distinct from a nanny parent (restarter) process. If you have observed "fail hang", you need watchdog to monitor keepalives. If only "fail crash", then there's no need.

Answer (score 5):

> if one thread/process/subsystem dereferences a null pointer, or access a non-existent vector entry, etc, I guess that it just dies(?) and the rest of the system ... limps along without it?

A null pointer failure inside a thread will require to end the whole process to where the thread belongs to (with all it's other threads). Fullstop. There is a high risk the adress space of the process is corrupted, which will affect not only the thread where the crash occured.

If other processes (not threads!) in your system are affected depends on how they interacted with the crashed process, and in case they did, how tolerant they are written. Maybe they are not affected because they don't communicate with the other processes directly. Maybe they can handle not-running other processes gracely. Failure tolerance in regards to other processes can be implemented with or without exception handling or signal handling, it does not really matter.

> A watchdog in main() could know the process Id of each thread, since it started them, and periodically check their status, killing and restarting any which are hanging or have died.

It seems you are confusing process IDs and threads here, so let me say this more clearly: only processes guarantee the necessary isolation to keep a system alive after a null pointer crash, not threads.

The idea of a watchdog or heart beat monitor is fine, but it needs to be implemented as a separate process, not in the `main` routine of an application which can potentially crash. The monitor process should be a very simple and small program, so simple that it has a very low risk of crashing itself.

> I use the term thread loosely; they might be processes

That's the problem: you should **use the terms more strictly** (and I am wondering actually why you don't - it seems you are talking about an existing system, so most decisions about threads and processes should have already been made).

Threads are lightweight and can easily communicate with each other through shared variables in memory - that's their benefit over processes. On the other hand, they don't provide the address space isolation you need to recover from a crash - that's their disadvantage.

This terminology is used today on most major platforms. I made a short Google search and from what I found, VxWorks is not really different from that (the docs call processes Real Time Processes, and threads Tasks - with a hint that thread and task are synonyms).

Comment: Thanks, Doc, for an informative answer. While I do know the difference between a process and a thread, I did not know how our system was structured when this assignment was thrown at me yesterday with instructions, as usual, to get to fixed last week :-) The bad news is that our C++ code builds on a framework, which we cannot alter, and which runs everything as threads, nor processes. I will add an update to the question, with a proposed solution and would very much welcome your comments on it.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica: I think before you create such a solution, you should have some statistics at hand how often it happens that the system crashes with a null pointer exception, and how often it happens that the system stalls / runs into an endless loop. Or maybe there are different crash scenarios like vector indexes out of range, or memory leaks?  So as always, *make sure you are solving the right problem* - when "endless loops" happen once every 3 years, you probably don't need to implement a heartbeat, a simple watchdog which monitors the process would be enough.

Comment: I hear what you say, but we need a solution before delivery to customer in a few months. We simply don't have the time. I also don't think that we have the time for subtlety  - just "if anything goes awry, (terminate and) restart the app". I guess that I could add statistic collation and revisit it after while in the field

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica: so you have a large program already which was never run in a production-like test environment, so you cannot collect any stats about the reliability? I think for a system which is developed over months before it gets into the customer enviroment, that's is something you will really need, otherwise expect the project to fail, regardless how many "just-in-case" handlers you will add to it.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica: then I don't understand your comment. For a program which has been used for years, your organization should have some information available about the frequency and type of crashes. And when your time is sparse, it is even more important that you invest it in solving the right problem.

Comment: Oh, it has been used - for years. But no failure data was ever collected, and now we have only a month or two before customer delivery. So, I have to stick in something; anything,as long as it improves on the nothing that we have now. After that, I will see what I can do. As is sadly normal, development and testing focus on the functionality of the app. Esoteric stuff such as logging (at least we have that), stability, load test, long duration test, etc tend to be forgotten until the last minute scramble ->

Comment: -> It happened on the previous project, and it will happen in the next. I am trying to push management into panic mode on this one, just to get the time to do the minimum.

Comment: Doc, no one has formally kept track. We can ask, but won't get any definite answer. Yes, we ***should have*** kept records, but everybody was too busy with the "actual functionality", to give much thought to "the twiddly bits around the edges". And that will be raised at the project post mortem, and "lessons will be learned", and we ***will*** make the same mistakes on the next project. Right now, I have had some good help here, for which much thanks, and have a rough proposal for a first pass which can be implemented before customer delivery, then hope to make it better going forward.

Comment: I still don't get it. When you run the system for years successfully for certain customers, what is so different in context of the new customer that you need to add extra failure handling now which was not necessary the last years?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica "The bad news is that our C++ code builds on a framework, which we cannot alter, and which runs everything as threads, nor processes."  Well, don't use the framework for your watchdog.  Make it a separate process.  You already (in the question) identified that the watchdog should be as simple as possible to reduce bug surface area.  Frameworks move complexity around; but they actually increase the total complexity.

Comment: @BenVoigt: maybe there is a misunderstanding of what the OP was describing, but "not using the framework for the watchdog" is missing the point. The watchdog itself can be as simple as shown in J_Hs answer under "nannies", but that will still not allow to continue the monitored application process when a single thread crashes with a severe error.

Comment: @DocBrown: Nothing will allow restarting only a single thread after process state has been corrupted (techniques such as checkpointing can be used to resume work in the brand-new process).  But having the watchdog as a separate process solves the problem of the watchdog becoming unstable due to application failure.  And the "framework forces everything to be a thread" is not an issue for a separate watchdog process, because the watchdog shall not use the framework anyway.

Comment: Everything I'm saying is repeating what's already in your answer, but OP used the framework limitations to object to your correct requirement of a separate process for the watchdog, so I thought I'd explain why the framework limitations do not apply to the watchdog.

Comment: @BenVoigt: *"OP used the framework limitations to object to your correct requirement of a separate process for the watchdog"* - that's not how I understood the OP's comment, I thought they meant they cannot easily replace the existing thread architecture of the main application by an architecture based on processes. I don't see any objection against the watchdog as a separate process.

Comment: OP will have a separate watchdog process that does not use the framework, plus one monolithic, single process, multi-threaded, app that does use the framework.

Comment: @DocBrown "I still don't get it. When you run the system for years successfully for certain customers". Sorry, you must have misunderstood. This is the first delivery of this product. I may have misled you by saying that every project (no matter which company I work for) tends to make the same mistakes. This project is just taking its turn at reinventing the mistake wheel.

Comment: I interpreted your statement *"Oh, it has been used - for years"* as a confirmation the product was already used in production for years (and since it wasn't delivered to your new customer, I was assuming it was used by others in the past. But when you think you need some process monitoring now, which you did not have in the past, start with something simple and see how far it takes you. I think J_H's advice is pretty good here, but I would start only with the simpler things (like "nannies") and break down into multiple processes only if you have data at hand which proofs that you must.

Answer (score 4):

> if one thread/process/subsystem dereferences a null pointer, or access a non-existent vector entry, etc, I guess that it just dies(?) and the rest of the system ... limps along without it?

No.

This means that the thread has invoked undefined behaviour, at which point your entire system is suspect - the thread can happily of overwritten memory being used by other threads, etc. You should restart the entire application, not just the offending thread.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's threads all the way down, alas. Our C++ code builds on a framework, which we cannot alter, and which runs everything as threads, nor processes. I will add an update to the question, with a proposed solution and would very much welcome your comments on it.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to remember in addition to everything else: Make sure that a process cannot get into a state where it stops making progress, but still manages to keep a watchdog timer alive.